# Convert all rows in a column with date format to text format

Tags: excel, vba, date, text, autofill

[image: Screenshot DATE format to Text Format]

I need to convert the column with Dates, formatted in Date formats into text format and if possible in reverse.
I can apply **worksheet function** TEXT, fill down by copy pasting or double clicking and then copy/cut the helper column and paste as value in the original column and record the macro, but is there any way to do so without selecting/activating, autofilling, using helper columns,(like "H" and "I") in this example? Will any vba function in place of worksheet function result in more efficiency?

```
Sub DateFormatToText()
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""dd/mm/yyyy"")"
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H20")
End Sub
```

Browsing through, I came to know those are not optimal codes.

Comment: You've tagged the question as VBA, so please, post the code you've tried.Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you've said *Date formats into text format and if possible in reverse*, so your formula should be `=TEXT(A1;"yyyy/mm/dd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no helper columns, no worksheet formulas

To change the date entries in the same column, something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub colGtoText()
    Dim v, i As Long, r As Range, ws As Worksheet

'define the working area of Column G entries  
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
With ws
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(1, "G"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    v = r.Value 'read into vba array for faster processing
End With

With r
    .NumberFormat = "@" 'change to text format

    'process each entry to the appropriately formatted text string
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If IsDate(v(i, 1)) Then v(i, 1) = Format(v(i, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Next i

    'write results back to the range from the vba array
    .Value = v
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below:

```
Range("H2:H" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=TEXT(G2,""dd/mm/yyyy"")"
```

Comment: Sir, thank you very much. Is it possible without using helper columns,(like "H" and "I") in this example, and using some VBA function in place of Worksheet Function ?

Comment: @Biswajit, I am not sure I understand your requirement. It will not be possible to have both results in one column (Column H and Column I). What exactly is the objective?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I think OP means changing the value of column G directly into text. Probably a loop in each cell would do it. Anyways, upvoted your answer.

Comment: Sir, the code is showing runtime error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error). I tried changing it to ActiveSheet.Range("H2:H" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(G2, "dd/mm/yyyy") but then it show result as 00/01/1900 for each row. Moreover is it possible to convert column G into text format directly without first changing in column H. Your answer resolved my issue, but I just want to know if it is possible at all.I don't actually need changed value in another column.

Comment: @Biswajit, my bad there was a typo in the code. I have fixed it now. For: Foxfire And Burns Burns: Understood. But since he was mentioning outputs of both columns I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT(G2,"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

used `-` operation either using Replace function